# Sorting the result - sunspot rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have two models, `School` model and `Price` model. Every school has a price. Right now I get back the result I want, but I like to implement a sorting function that sorts the highest price for a school and the lowest.

**School-controller:**

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
def index
 @query = params[:search]
 @search = School.search(:include => [:price] do 
   fulltext params[:search]
     paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 7
   end
 @results = @search.results
end
end
```

**School-model:**

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :price
 # sunspot search
  searchable do
   text :name, :locality
  end
end
```

**Index - view**

```
<ul>
   # Cheapest price
   <li><span class="label label-ord">Show cheapest price <%= @query %></span></li>
   # Highest price
   <li><span class="label label-ord">Show highest price <%= @query %></span></li>
</ul>
<% for result in @results %>
   <tr>
    # School name, from the school-model
    <td><h3><%= link_to result.name, result %></h3></td>
    # School price, from the price-model
    <td><h3><%= result.prices.min %> kr</h3></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

How can I sort the highest and lowest price; should I use facets or methods? How do I do that?

Comment: @MrYoshiji - Any ideas? or documentation links?

Comment: your question is ambiguous. Do you want to get the highest and lowest price on all the results, or do you want to sort the results by price ascending / descending ? Moreover, do you want them to be the highest / lowest prices of all search results, or only on paginated results ?

Comment: @m_x on all the results and sort the result ascending and descendig.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know sunspot really well, so i'm a bit guessing around here... Please consider what follows as a lead or advice, because i'm definitely not sure this will work.

The first step is to index the price for each school :

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices

  searchable do
    text :name, :locality
    double :price do
      # 'value' is just an example, use the relevant field on the price object
      price.value if price.present? 
    end
  end
end
```

Then reindex. Now you can order your searches:

```
 @search = School.search( include: [:prices] ) do 
   fulltext params[:search]
   paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 7
   order_by :price, :asc # or use any param of your choice, 
                         # returned by a select tag for example
 end
```

**Update**

You can stick this logic in a class method.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.custom_search( text, page, order = :asc )
    search( include: [:prices] ) do 
      fulltext text
      paginate page: page, per_page: 7
      order_by :price, order
    end
  end
end
```

then call with:

```
School.custom_search params[:search], params[:page]
# or :
School.custom_search params[:search], params[:page], :desc
```

Comment: mabye this can work, I get this error when I try to reindex: undefined method `any?' for #<Price:0x007fc78a2d5f60> Is it because I eager load the price model?

Comment: ... ok, did not understand that price was a one-to-one association... i'll edit my answer

Comment: I would like to know how to make them like methods like your previous answer. One for desc and the other for asc.

Comment: really ? i don't mean to be rude, but 5 minutes of googling would get you there. In your case, something like `link_to "search", schools_path( search: "a search", page: 1, order: "asc" )`. remember to sanitize this, though - especially the order string. Oh, and if you just need to link to the same page with same params except, for example, another order, you can do: `url_for( order: "desc" )` instead of `schools_path` or whatever route you used.